# Generate non-fixed length large random number (bigint)

Tags: php, mysql

How can I generate a non-fixed length large random number? (e.g. within the range of MySQL's bigint). The `mt_rand()` function does not support such large numbers.

Comment: Are you running a 32bit PHP or a 64-bit PHP?

Comment: So what is it, `non-fixed/limitless` or `limited by mysql bigint range` ? ;-)

Comment: Maybe limited by mysql bigint range, maybe between 1 billion and 1 trillion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple random functions:

```
const max_limit=10000;
a=mt_rand()*max_limit*max_limit + mt_rand()*max_limit + mt_rand();
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's BIGINT is 8 bytes large. Let's asume an unsigned BIGINT.

```
echo unpack('H*', mcrypt_create_iv(8))[1];
```

or for php versions < 5.4 that do not support function array dereferencing

```
echo current(unpack('H*', mcrypt_create_iv(8)));
```

see:
http://docs.php.net/function.mcrypt-create-iv
http://docs.php.net/function.pack